# How to create column based on string position of other column in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

df:

```
    Col_A     
0   011011   
1   011011   
2   011011   
3   011011   
4   011011
```

How to create a column based on string position, for example in column_A I need to check 0 position create a column B.

Output;

```
    Col_A     Col_B
0   011011   pos1,pos4
1   000111   pos1,pos2,pos3
2   011000   pos1,pos4,pos5,pos6
3   011111   pos1
4   011010   pos1,pos4,pos6
```

Comment: why column A is changed in output data?

Comment: Please reformat your question. The question is hard to understand and unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert strings to `DataFrame` and add columns names by function in `rename`:

```
f = lambda x: f'pos{x+1}'
df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df['Col_A']], index=df.index).rename(columns=f)
print (df1)
  pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6
0    0    1    1    0    1    1
1    0    0    0    1    1    1
2    0    1    1    0    0    0
3    0    1    1    1    1    1
4    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

Then compare `'0'` values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and for new column use matrix multiplication by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with remove separator by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['Col_B'] = df1.eq('0').dot(df1.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
print (df)

    Col_A                Col_B
0  011011            pos1,pos4
1  000111       pos1,pos2,pos3
2  011000  pos1,pos4,pos5,pos6
3  011111                 pos1
4  011010       pos1,pos4,pos6
```

Comment: Alternate to avoid extra `.str.rstrip`: `[','.join(df1.columns[mask]) for mask in df1.eq('0').to_numpy()]`